# Win 10 - Transfer files non-domain to domain PC without access to domain controller

Tags: windows-10, security, file-transfer, active-directory, domain

I have a situation where a domain PC and non-domain PC are networked. They need to transfer files between each other. The domain PC usually has connection to the domain controller (DC) but due to communication interruptions it sometimes can't access the DC. I need to ensure the file transfers continue during interruptions to the DC.

I can run the service that is responsible for the file transfers on an account I specify.

Using an AD account is problematic because it can not be authenticated during interruptions to the DC so when the domain PC is "offline" to the domain network the AD authentication will fail.

Using the local account on both domain and non-domain PC is not allowed per security policy. (Wouldn't both accounts need to have the same password on both machines as well?)

Windows 10 has disabled guest access to remote files without authentication and there are security concerns with re-enabling it.

I'm out of ideas - hopefully I've overlooked something.

Edit:
Some more information is the solution in place on Win 7 uses standard Windows CIFS/SMB and the \COMPUTERNAME\Location designation to move the files. Authentication is accomplished using the same local administrator account on both machines and running the responsible service on this account.

With Win 10 I need to move away from utilizing the local account.

Comment: You're probably going to be using IP addresses, and you'll need to choose a protocol appropriate to your needs. SSH, SFTP, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Some more information is the solution in place on Win 7 uses standard Windows CIFS/SMB and the \\COMPUTERNAME\Location designation to move the files. Authentication is accomplished using the same local administrator account on both machines and running the responsible service on this account. 

With Win 10 I need to move away from utilizing the local account.

Comment: When adding more information, use the EDIT button and add this information to the body of the question. This has the effect of improving the question, and that is always a good thing.

Comment: Thank you! Added it. Long time reader of Stack Exchange but first time I've had to post.